# Why use armeabi-v7a code over armeabi code?

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm, armv7

In my current project I make use of multiple .so files. These are located at the armeabi and armeabi-v7a folder. Unfortunately one of the .so files is a 6MB and I need to reduce file size. Instead of having a fat APK file, I would like to use just the armeabi files and remove the armeabi-v7a folder.

According to the NDK documentation, armeabi-v7a code is extended armeabi code which can contain extra CPU instructions. This all goes beyond my expertise, but I question why one would like to have both armeabi-v7a and armeabi code. There must be a good reason to have both, right?

On my test devices this all seem to work fine. These have ARM v7 CPU's. Is it safe to assume that everything works now?

Comment: You might want to give this blogpost a read now.  It is thorough and up-to-date: https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/tag/armeabi-v7a/

Comment: And now the doc says: `armeabi is deprecated in NDK r16. Removed in NDK r17. No hard float.`

Comment: For those coming later, take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28926101/is-it-safe-to-support-only-armeabi-v7a-for-android-4-and-above).

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Depends on what your native code does, but v7a has support for hardware floating point operations, which makes a huge difference. armeabi will work fine on all devices, but will be a lot slower, and won't take advantage of newer devices' CPU capabilities. Do take some benchmarks for your particular application, but removing the armeabi-v7a binaries is generally not a good idea. If  you need to reduce size, you might want to have two separate apks for older (armeabi) and newer (armeabi-v7a) devices.

**Update 2012-09;** Google's Play Store finally has support for uploading different APKs (each targeting a different CPU architecture), with the so-called "multiple APKs" feature:
https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks

> Where *maybe* each APK needs to have a different version code (even if they all are actually the same version, just with different CPU target).

But *Update 2023;* Google recommends creating "App bundle" instead of using "multiple APKs" feature:
https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle

> Where for "App bundle", the Play store can automatically bring down the download size, based on the device which's downloading.

Comment: Thanks for your clear reply. It will be a good idea to do benchmarking as well of splitting the application in 2 APK files. The latter is actually a very good idea! Many thanks!

Comment: Where Can I find difference between the both ABI ? I'm very instersted to understand real differences...

Comment: ARM manuals? http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0344c/Cacciced.html

Comment: Not really. You are limited by Google Play used to differentiate APKs (screen size, target version, etc). There are some apps that have their native libs as a 'plugin' of sorts, but you need to download another APK for you platform. Check MX Player for example.

Comment: Long overdue. They seem to still recommend single APK when possible though.

Comment: Is the phrase "separate apks for older (armeabi) and newer (armeabi-v7a) devices" the same as "separate apks for older (armv5) and newer (armv7a) devices"?

Comment: Kind of. I *think* the only released Android devices before armv7a are all armv5 (G1, Magic, etc.).

Comment: The older devices are actually ARMv6, but Android used ARMv5TE as the baseline.  There's very little reason to build for pre-v7 hardware today.

Answer (score 60):

EABI = Embedded Application Binary Interface. It is such specifications to which an executable must conform in order to execute in a specific execution environment. It also specifies various aspects of compilation and linkage required for interoperation between toolchains used for the ARM Architecture. In this context when we speak about *armeabi* we speak about ARM architecture and GNU/Linux OS. Android follows the little-endian ARM GNU/Linux ABI.

armeabi application will run on ARMv5 (e.g. ARM9) and ARMv6 (e.g. ARM11). You may use Floating Point hardware if you build your application using proper GCC options like *-mfpu=vfpv3 -mfloat-abi=softfp* which tells compiler to generate floating point instructions for VFP hardware and enables the soft-float calling conventions. armeabi doesn't support hard-float calling conventions (it means FP registers are not used to contain arguments for a function), but FP operations in HW are still supported.

armeabi-v7a application will run on Cortex A# devices like Cortex A8, A9, and A15. It supports multi-core processors and it supports *-mfloat-abi=hard*. So, if you build your application using *-mfloat-abi=hard*, many of your function calls will be faster.

Comment: According to https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html:
`The armeabi-v7a ABI uses the -mfloat-abi=softfp switch`.  So what do you mean by **supports -mfloat-abi=hard**?

Answer (score 9):

> Instead of having a fat APK file, I would like to use just the armeabi files and remove the armeabi-v7a folder.

The opposite is a much better strategy. If you have `minSdkVersion` to 14 and upload your apk to the play store, you'll notice you'll support the same number of devices whether you support `armeabi` or not. Therefore, there are no devices with Android 4 or higher which would benefit from `armeabi` at all.

This is probably why the Android NDK doesn't even support `armeabi` anymore as per revision r17b. [[source](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/revision_history)]