# Android dev - which CPU architecture should my app support?

Tags: android, sdk, cpu-architecture

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/sdks/android

"The subdirectories contain the native components, built for each supported Android platform. You can safely omit some of them if you know which platforms your app needs to support ("armeabi" is the most common)."

I have a simple application about text notes.
Based on text above - which libs should I include:
Only armeabi or all presented (mips, x86, armeabi, armeabi-7a also)?

Tried to find some detailed info about these armeabis - no result.
What for are they?

Comment: Hmmmmmm ... I've asked, support of which platforms should I include in my project - cause .apk file size depends on that.

Anyway, Tomaski answered what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be fine with just armeabi, unless you need some additional CPU instructions - in that case armeabi-7a

have a look here for more detailed answer: [/why-use-armeabi-v7a-code-over-armeabi-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080525/why-use-armeabi-v7a-code-over-armeabi-code) and here for some background info: [ArmEabiPort](https://wiki.debian.org/ArmEabiPort)

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Do I understand correct, that most of today's devices have armeabi architecture (unless some extra operations from armeabi-v7 are needed)?

Comment: to my best knowledge - yes. 
x86 is basically a pc and MIPS are ambeedded systems (routers, game consoles etc)