# Which is the best database to use with Unity for UWP?

Tags: database, sqlite, unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens

I have a Unity project built for Android, which uses an SQLite database. But, when i switched platforms to UWP i get these errors:

`Reference to type 'Component' claims it is defined in 'System', but it could not be found`
`Reference to type 'ICloneable' claims it is defined in 'mscorlib', but it could not be found`

I read that this is because of the incompatibility of the SQLite libraries with UWP. So, i couldn't use `System.Data`and `Mono.Data.SQLite`.

The only solution i could find was to use `SQLite4Unity3D` as per this link:

https://github.com/codecoding/SQLite4Unity3d

But with this i could not find a replacement for `Read()` function in `DataReader`, to read data row by row.

What is the best possible solution to this?

Comment: Have your tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50753569/setup-database-sqlite-for-unity/50808156?s=1|42.3994#50808156) instruction?

Comment: @Programmer: That instruction doesn't have anything pertaining to UWP. My application works perfectly with Android.

Comment: I don't care if it works with Android or not an yes, I saw the flag in this question. Follow that instruction. When you reach to the "Setting up the UNMANAGED code part" section, simply copy everything from [this](https://github.com/codecoding/SQLite4Unity3d/tree/master/Example/Assets/Plugins/WSA) folder to your "Plugins" folder.

Comment: @Programmer:  I did exactly what was mentioned. It still doesn't work/gives the same error. What i learned from other posts is that Mono.Data.Sqlite does not work with UWP.

Comment: After following the instruction, make sure to delete the old dll's you were using. Finally, switch the  scripting backend to IL2CPP.

Comment: [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1462406/il2cpp-missing.html) says not to use IL2CPP. Would it be a problem? Also, would i have to install unity all over again to get it, if it isn't installed?

Comment: You can use IL2CPP with Hololens. You don't have to re-install Unity if IL2CPP is not installed. Simply find the installer (UnityDownloadAssistant) for the current version Unity you're using. Open it and **de-select** everything. Now, select  "Windows Store IL2CPP scripting Backend" and "Windows IL2CPP scripting Backend". That's it.

Comment: @Programmer:  Reference Rewriter found some errors while running with command --target="Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp.dll error occurred along with list of other dlls that were pasted into the plugins folder based on the instructions, when it was built with IL2CPP.

Comment: What's your Unity version?

Comment: @Programmer Unity 2018.1.0f2

Comment: It should work then. See [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/errors-building-uwp-with-sqlite-for-xbox-one.520078/) post about using "mcs.rsp" and "csc.rsp" to fix it. It means you have to move those dll's such as System.Data.dll outside the Assets folder but in the project root folder. Read [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/errors-building-uwp-with-sqlite-for-xbox-one.520078/#post-3410877)

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked.

Comment: Anytime. Updated my other answer to add uwp support.

Comment: @Programmer: I'm sorry. It still have problems. Am i to set scripting runtime version to .NET 4.x?

Comment: The tutorial doesn't say you have to but since you're using UWP, you will probably need to. If you have issues, try the .NET 4.x.

Comment: @Programmer It had built successfully without any scripts. Now when i add a script, i get errors like System.Data.Common.DbDataReader is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.

Comment: @Programmer Also intellisense stops showing Unity keywords in VS.

Comment: You referenced all the dll's in the "mcs.rsp" and "csc.rsp"  file? There should be 7 of them(dlls)

Comment: @Programmer:  Like-  `-r:System.Data.dll -r:Mono.Data.Sqite.dll` etc, right?

Comment: Replying to your deletedd comment. No. Not just that. Very close. You have to do it to all of the dlls an the spellings must be correct. The spelling in your last comment isn't fine. See the UWP section in the duplicate. You can just copy it from 3C section in the duplicate.