# Unable to load DLL - SQLite3

Tags: sqlite, unity-game-engine, android-sqlite

I want to set up a local database for my Unity-based application.
Up to now, I have followed this tutorial post to setup all things:
[SQLite and Unity: How to do it right](https://medium.com/@rizasif92/sqlite-and-unity-how-to-do-it-right-31991712190)

Within my Unity Editor, all things working properly without any problem but when I execute the game build within Android device, it was giving me this kind of error message:

[image]

With a similar error message, I read many posts and tried different approaches but nothing worked for me so I have decided to post the question here.

At present, this kind of setup I have for sqlite3:
[image]

To give me some suggestion still if you require some details then let me know.

**EDIT:** .so file inspector detail
[image]

Comment: The main problem seems to be that the sqlite3 plugin dll is not deployed to the standalone app to the device.
I have not worked with plugins for android yet, but Android is not included according to your import settings. Look in the android libs and include the dll for standalone build.

Look on SO or google, if anyone has tried to use plugins on android and how to do it

Comment: Within armeabi-v7a and x86 folders, there are libsqlite3.so files exist - this I want to inform you

Comment: Maybe you find some information here
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidNativePlugins.html

Comment: It might be that you have to wrap around the .so plugin code in an extra class or add architecture dependent code

Answer (score 0):

According to the information provided and the information from you, I would suggest that the .so plugin file just needs to have Android selected. You may have to manually add the methods according to the information in

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidNativePlugins.html

I hope that helps

Comment: I have already done this with so files already and added more details in the question.

Comment: Ok, any improvement of your situation? You may have to wrap the functions in libsqlite3.so in an extra class

Comment: You may have to do a lot of "[DllImport ("pluginName")]
private static extern float Foopluginmethod();" declarations by yourself if there is no C# / Mono wrapper for the libsqlite3

Comment: Maybe you can find information here

https://forum.unity.com/threads/simplesql-sqlite-integration-with-unity3d.143442/page-12#post-4551331

Comment: Or try the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50753569/setup-database-sqlite-for-unity