# Is it safe to support only armeabi-v7a for Android 4 and above?

Tags: android, android-ndk, arm

I have developed an app which is mostly in C++ and is compiled by NDK to `.so` libraries as usual. We know that native apps have to be build for each CPU architecture separately; So I have different `so` files for `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a`. (I deliberately left out `x86` and `mips`, since not many Android devices with these architectures are released.)

However, the size is very big and each `so` file takes about `90 MB` of space and I want to reduce it.

I know I can leave out `armeabi-v7a`, because of backward compatibility, but in that case the app will run very slowly.

Considering the fact that my app supports only android ICS and above (`minSdkVersion="14"`), Can I safely remove `armeabi` and suppose that all of these new devices use `armeabi-v7a`? Or some of the devices may still use the old `armeabi` and not `armeabi-v7a` architectures?

Comment: If  you already have device having newer api version and you want to test your app on old devices only then download armabi-v7a

Comment: You can do it "safely" in the sense that the Play Store won't send an app that only supports ARMv7-A to older devices. The only risk you take is cutting off some percentage of your market. There were a surprisingly large number of ARMv6 devices a few years back, but that number is in decline due to the availability of cheap ARMv7-A+ chips for the low end.

Comment: Yeah it's true that play store filters apps according to device specifications, but since my company is not going to distribute it via Play Store, it won't help much and I had to make sure.

Comment: Please know that NDK since r16 deprecated armeabi and mips. Thus so files for these architectures would not be generated by default. One can still get so files by explicitly mentioning in abifilters. This actually means armeabi and mips are definitely not required now.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The unmodified, original Android source for Android 4.0 and newer doesn't support ARMv5/ARMv6 by default (but can be modified to build for ARMv5/ARMv6 - there are custom builds of it that run on ARMv6). I'm not sure if one can get an ARMv6 device certified compatible with such Android releases, or if it only is applicable for unofficial firmwares. Since Android 4.4, the CDD (compatibility definition) strictly requires ARMv7. See https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34958/what-are-the-minimum-hardware-specifications-for-android for details on this.

So yes, maybe, in principle, you could drop `armeabi` if your app requires Android 4.0, but I'm not sure if there is any such official guarantee. If you require Android 4.4, it should absolutely be fine though.

Comment: Ok thanks. Now that I know if even such devices exist, their number won't be much, I think cutting out armeabi is the best thing, since it saves 90 MB of space, which is A LOT!

Comment: I run Android 4.4.4 with ARMv6 and I also use Play Store.
Leave the user to choose what it want, you could also create a separate version for ARMv6 and maybe update it less often than the main version but stop supporting it isn't nice.

Answer (score 9):

There are no Android 4+ devices which support `armeabi` but not `armeabi-v7a`, so you can safely drop `armeabi`.

You can check this yourself in Google Play: create 2 APK's (1 which supports `armeabi` and 1 which supports `armeabi-v7a`) and try uploading both to Google Play. You'll notice they have the same number of supported devices.

You will even get an error when uploading to Google Play if you split your APK by architecture while trying to support both architectures:

> Version xxx of this app can not be downloaded by any devices as they
>   will all receive APKs with higher version codes.

Answer (score 0):

As a zenfone 2 owner I would say no - these devices run ICS+ but with x86 microarchitecture. If you search android x86 percent on google you should be able to come across a unity page telling you the market share of different microarchitecture. Also, there're a few niche products using MIPS-bases CPUs and run ICS+.

While there do have a mechanism to let x86 android devices run apk compiled without a so for x86, that have other drawbacks.