# Android armeabi devices with API level 15+

Tags: android-ndk

I'm developing an app for API level 15+ that has some jni code and i'm wondering if there are devices with armeabi ABI (ARMv5) and API level 15+

Can i include only armeabi-v7a and x86 libraries and skip the old armeabi?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Android itself doesn't support ARM versions below ARMv7 from Android 4.4 (API level 19). Since Android 4.0 (API level 15), it doesn't support ARMv5/ARMv6 by default but can be modified to build for those platforms (see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-building/Q_gU1zb6DLc/Bq5QryioQ_kJ), and there are custom builds that run on ARMv6. I'm not entirely sure if there are any official, certified compatible devices that run such a combination (Android 4.0-4.3) though - there should at least not be any such certified devices running Android 4.4, since the compatibility definition document strictly requires ARMv7 from that version.

So in practice you should be pretty safe to skip it, but you might exclude some fringe third party ROMs by doing that.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28926267/3115956 for a similar answer to a similar question.

Comment: Nice info, but I got confused. ARMv6 is supported up to 4.0, and then ARMv7 is supported until 4.4, is that so? Otherwise I'm missing some versions between ARMv6 and ARMv7 :)

Comment: No - from 4.4, only ARMv7 is allowed (plus the other architectures such as x86 and mips), i.e. there are no officially compliant devices running Android 4.4 on ARMv6. From Android 4.0 to 4.3, the Android source itself doesn't build for ARMv6 any longer out of the box, but manufacturers can modify the source to make it build for ARMv6, and there is no strict requirement saying that you cannot make devices with ARMv6 for those Android versions. So from Android 4.0, devices with ARMv6 should be much less common, and from Android 4.4, there should not be any more ARMv6 at all.

Answer (score 0):

Can i include only armeabi-v7a and x86 libraries and skip the old armeabi?

No, iff app is to be used on old cpu based architecture devices.

And Yes, if we are sure that no customer have older than ARM7 cpu based architecture device.

In our case we purchased the Chilkat licence for one year and they happily supported with ARMEABI .SO files. Hence it is upto the use case. It is affordable for and organisation.

Also wants to share the contact point for Chilkat if anyone wants to contact them for help. Email them  at -> support@chilkatsoft.com

Thank you and Happy coding!!!