# What's rule does Android system load native library(so file) from armeabi,armeabi-v7a,arm64-v8a?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Assume we have a jni folder structure below.

```
armeabi
    a.so
    b.so
armeabi-v7a
    a.so
```

On a ARMv7-based device, I want to load b.so, but the there is no b.so under folder "armeabi-v7a", so will the system report a not found library error or use the b.so under folder "armeabi"?

And even more, what order does system look for a so file among `armeabi`,`armeabi-v7a`,`arm64-v8a`,`x86`,`x86_64`? For example, on a x86_64-based device, system look for the so file in folder `x86_64` first, but if not found, will system continue to look for the file in `x86`,`arm64-v8a`,`armeabi-v7a`,`armeabi` in sequence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen: http://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#am

I believe it answers your questions:

> Both the Play Store and Package Manager expect to find NDK-generated
>     libraries on filepaths inside the APK matching the following pattern:

```
/lib/<abi>/lib<name>.so
```

> If the system does not find the native shared libraries where it expects
>       them, it cannot use them. In such a case, the app itself has to copy the 
>       libraries over, and then perform dlopen().

Further down the page is this particular bit:

> **Automatic extraction of native code at install time**
>
> When installing an application, the package manager service scans the APK, and looks for any shared libraries of the form:

```
lib/<primary-abi>/lib<name>.so
```

> If none is found, and you have defined a secondary ABI, the service scans for shared libraries of the form:

```
lib/<secondary-abi>/lib<name>.so
```

> When it finds the libraries that it's looking for, the package manager copies them to /lib/lib.so, under the application's data directory (data/data//lib/).
>   If there is no shared-object file at all, the application builds and installs, but crashes at runtime.

So in your case if you are on a armeabi-v7a architecture, you'll have to copy the `lib/armeabi/libb.so` file over and use dlopen() as the PackageManager knows nothing of what needs to be loaded in your app but did find something in the `lib/armeabi-v7a` directory.

Comment: If we have libraries in the right folders, do we still need to manually load them? surprisingly my android works fine without explicit `LoadLibrary` call

Comment: I am just loading one library and it's dependencies are loaded automatically without any explicit call to LoadLibrary

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Morrison Chang's answer, one could always consider dropping the `armeabi` part altogether (so you don't need two copies of the lib, which I guess is large). In practice, there are very few modern devices (running Android 4.0 or newer) that support `armeabi` but not `armeabi-v7a` (and none since Android 4.4). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30924571/3115956, https://stackoverflow.com/a/28926267/3115956 for a few cases of that. That will reduce the file size without losing support for any significant part of your target userbase, assuming that you require Android 4.0. If you still target older versions, it's more of a reason to keep `armeabi` though.

Comment: in addition to this, there are still so many cheap devices (less than $80 phones, especially chinese made phones) that run on Android 4.0-4.3 that still use old ARMv6.

Comment: Are those devices also fully certified (i.e. come with google play store), or just android-compatible devices?