# How to get android app for ARMv6 architecture with crosswalk webview plugin from PhoneGap Build?

Tags: android, webview, armv7, crosswalk, armv6

After adding crosswalk webview plugin to my app I recieve either x86 version or ARMv7 version. But I want my app to work also on devices with ARMv6 architecture and as much as I know app set for ARMv6 architecture works on ARMv7 as well but this for ARMv7 doesn't work on ARMv6. And that's why I want to do get version for ARMv6. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You do realize that Android support for ARMv6 was dropped in AOSP in 4.0: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28926267/295004

Comment: So it means that ARMv6 architecture already died? There is no way to create an app for ARMv6 anymore? And one more question. If I make ARMv7 app will I be able to run it on coming ARMv8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want ARMv6 [really ARMv5TE] on Crosswalk, I believe you'll need to build it yourself. See: https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk/issues/619

Also if you have ARMv7 binary that should run on ARMv8, also know as arm64-v8a.

See: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
and from this ARM document: https://www.arm.com/files/downloads/ARMv8_Architecture.pdf

> Maintain full compatibility with ARMv7

Update in response to questions in comment:

I've never tried it but here are the instructions on building Android Crosswalk from source:

https://crosswalk-project.org/contribute/building_crosswalk/android_build.html

Looks like you'll need to be running a 64-bit Linux OS to do it.

I would expect ARMv6 (armeabi) to be supported as Android's Compatibility Definition Document, mandates certain 32-bit instructions for support:

https://source.android.com/compatibility/7.1/android-7.1-cdd.html#3_3_2_32-bit_arm_native_code_compatibility

and ARMv5TE is still listed in the NDK documentation:
https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html

Should Android start to deprecate the armeabi binary target I would expect a great deal of lead time.

Comment: And how can I build it by myself? Which version of plugin should I download? And my ARMv6 app will work on new devices? (I only heard about that but I'm not sure)